# How to test if a shape and a panel are at the same location

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, collision-detection

The idea is that you must shoot the panel. So the panel will be set to a random location at the top of the screen and then move down to the bottom of the screen. You must shoot the panel with the shapes before it reaches the bottom. But I dont know how to test if the created shape is at the location of the panel to reset the panel. At the moment this is my code but the if tests false.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, jpeg;

const
  MaxRays=100;
  RayStep=8;
type
   TForm1 = class(TForm)
   Panel1: TPanel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    Button1: TButton;
    Shape1: TShape;
    Timer3: TTimer;
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
       MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
     procedure Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Rays:array[0..MaxRays-1] of TShape;

   public
   procedure StartPanelAnimation1;
   procedure DoPanelAnimationStep1;
   function  PanelAnimationComplete1: Boolean;
   { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
 var key : char;
{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }



 { TForm1 }

 procedure TForm1.DoPanelAnimationStep1;
begin
Panel1.Top := Panel1.Top+1;
end;

function TForm1.PanelAnimationComplete1: Boolean;
begin
 Result := Panel1.Top=512;
end;

procedure TForm1.StartPanelAnimation1;
begin
  Panel1.Top := 0;
  Timer1.Interval := 1;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
   DoPanelAnimationStep1;
   if PanelAnimationComplete1 then
    StartPanelAnimation1;
   if (shape1.Top < panel1.Top) and (shape1.Left < panel1.Left+104) and (shape1.Left >       panel1.Left)   then
   begin
    startpanelanimation1;
    sleep(10);
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 button1.Hide;
  key := 'a';
  timer2.Enabled := true;
  StartPanelAnimation1; 
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 shape1.Visible := false;
 timer2.Enabled := false;
 end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
   begin
image1.Left := image1.Left-10;
end;

 procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    begin
    image1.Left := image1.Left+10;
   end;

procedure TForm1.Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to MaxRays-1 do
    if Rays[i]<>nil then
    begin
      Rays[i].Top:=Rays[i].Top-RayStep;
      if Rays[i].Top<0 then FreeAndNil(Rays[i]);
    end;
end;


procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
   var
   i:integer;
begin
  i:=0;
  while (i<MaxRays) and (Rays[i]<>nil) do inc(i);
  if i<MaxRays then
   begin
    Rays[i]:=TShape.Create(Self);
    Rays[i].Shape:=stEllipse;
    Rays[i].Pen.Color:=clRed;
    Rays[i].Pen.Style:=psSolid;
    Rays[i].Brush.Color:=clYellow;
    Rays[i].Brush.Style:=bsSolid;
    Rays[i].SetBounds(X-4,Y-20,9,41);
    Rays[i].Parent:=Self;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to MaxRays-1 do Rays[i]:=nil;
end;

end.
```

I have tried what @NGLN has said but when I i click the the mouse button the shape moves like 10 pixels then stops, when it stops the panel which was moving down normally is now moving like crazy at the top of the screen changing its left position but the top position stays 0.

Here Is the new code

```
unit Unit1;

interface


uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, jpeg;

  const
  MaxRays=100;
  RayStep=8;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Timer2: TTimer;
    Button1: TButton;
    Shape1: TShape;
    Timer3: TTimer;
    Image1: TImage;
    Timer4: TTimer;
    procedure Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
      Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Rays:array[0..MaxRays-1] of TShape;
  public
   procedure StartPanelAnimation1;
   procedure DoPanelAnimationStep1;
   function  PanelAnimationComplete1: Boolean;
   function EllipticShapeIntersectsPanel(Shape: TShape; Panel: TPanel): Boolean;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
 var key : char;
{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }



{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.DoPanelAnimationStep1;
begin
Panel1.Top := Panel1.Top+1;
end;

function TForm1.PanelAnimationComplete1: Boolean;
begin
 Result := Panel1.Top=512;
end;

procedure TForm1.StartPanelAnimation1;
var left : integer;
begin
  Panel1.Top := 0;
  randomize;
  left := random(clientwidth-105);
  panel1.Left := left;
  Timer1.Interval := 1;
   Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
 var I: Integer;
begin
 DoPanelAnimationStep1;
  if PanelAnimationComplete1 then
    StartPanelAnimation1;
   I := 0;
  while (Rays[I] <> nil) and (I < MaxRays)  do
  begin
    if EllipticShapeIntersectsPanel(Rays[I], Panel1) then
    Inc(I);
    startpanelanimation1;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 button1.Hide;
 key := 'a';
 timer2.Enabled := true;
 StartPanelAnimation1;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 shape1.Visible := false;
 timer2.Enabled := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
image1.Left := image1.Left-10;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
 image1.Left := image1.Left+10;
end;


procedure TForm1.Timer3Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to MaxRays-1 do
    if Rays[i]<>nil then
    begin
      Rays[i].Top:=Rays[i].Top-RayStep;
      if Rays[i].Top<0 then FreeAndNil(Rays[i]);
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
 var
  i:integer;
  left : integer;
  top : integer;
begin
  i:=0;
  while (i<MaxRays) and (Rays[i]<>nil) do i:= i+10;
  if i<MaxRays then
   begin
    Rays[i]:=TShape.Create(Self);
    Rays[i].Shape:=strectangle;;
    Rays[i].Pen.Color:=clRed;
    Rays[i].Pen.Style:=psSolid;
    Rays[i].Brush.Color:=clred;
    Rays[i].Brush.Style:=bsSolid;
    left := image1.Left+38;
    top := image1.Top-30;
    Rays[i].SetBounds(left,top,9,33);
    Rays[i].Parent:=Self;
   end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Screen.Cursor:=crNone;
end;

function TForm1.EllipticShapeIntersectsPanel(Shape: TShape;
  Panel: TPanel): Boolean;
var
  ShapeRgn: HRGN;
begin
  with Shape.BoundsRect do
    ShapeRgn := CreateEllipticRgn(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
  try
    Result := RectInRegion(ShapeRgn, Panel.BoundsRect);
  finally
    DeleteObject(ShapeRgn);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your shapes are elliptical, create a temporarilly region and determine intersection with a rectangle with [`RectInRegion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162906(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
function EllipticShapeIntersectsPanel(Shape: TShape; Panel: TPanel): Boolean;
var
  ShapeRgn: HRGN;
begin
  with Shape.BoundsRect do
    ShapeRgn := CreateEllipticRgn(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
  try
    Result := RectInRegion(ShapeRgn, Panel.BoundsRect);
  finally
    DeleteObject(ShapeRgn);
  end;
end;
```

*(If the shapes are [rectangular](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9e20538c-5132-4057-851a-34354d3ee088/view-source), then you can use the routine of [Darthman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063136/757830).)*

Now feed each ray in your array to this routine:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer2Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  ...
  I := 0;
  while (Rays[I] <> nil) and (I < MaxRays)  do
  begin
    if EllipticShapeIntersectsPanel(Rays[I], Panel1) then
      // Do what you want to do
    Inc(I);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Smart thinking. Alternatively, you could do a rudimentary check on the panel and the bounding rectangle of the circle, and then use Pythagoras theorem to do a finer check. More programming, though, and there are other things to optimize first if you use shapes to build a game with. ;)

Comment: @Craig If on the next timer interval one or more of the shapes collide with the panel, then this code runs again, and again... In your code you use `Sleep(10)`. I expect that to be the reason. Do something in this routine to prevent it from happening again. For example: purge the ray from the array.

Comment: @NGLN I have tried what you said but when I i click the the mouse button the shape moves like 10 pixels then stops, when it stops the panel which was moving down normally is now moving like crazy at the top of the screen changing its left position constantly but the top position stays 0. Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: @Craig Look, you asked how to calculate whether two controls collide, not how to write a complete game. Answers are given to the question, and seem sufficient to me. Sorry, but we can and may not address your additional questions in comments. Please post them separately.

Answer (score 2):

```
  if IntersectRect(Panel1.BoundsRect, Shape1.Boundsrect) then
  // collided
```

Comment: The shapes are elliptical, but maybe this is sufficient for OP.

Comment: So, perhaps you need to use mathematics to solve this. There is no possible ways to do it _easy_. If this ellipse is stretched only with one dimention you can try to check collision rect vs circle with some coefficient that determining stretch of circle.

Comment: The math for both circles and ellipses isn't thát tough, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13065119/757830) seems pretty easy to me though.

Comment: You can also do it pretty easy with perpixel check. First you must check IntersectRect for Rect and bounds for ellipse. Then if there is intersection you check every pixel in this intersection. For example if your ellipse is red, you must check pixels for red. Finally if there no even one red pixel in this rect - then there is no real intersection. This method will work with any shape. But as you can see there is limitation for color, it can't be gradient or so. In this case you must draw buffer similar to scene with simple colored shapes and then check intersection as I said above.

Comment: Yes, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13065119/757830) is pretty easy and usefull.

Comment: I get this error when I put your code in [Error] Unit1.pas(74): Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter

Comment: @Darthman Can you please help me i get this error "[Error] Unit1.pas(74): Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter" when using your code any suggestions on what is wrong?

Comment: I think that problem in constant and var parameters as compiler said. You must pass 1 var parameter and 2 const parameters. `if IntersectRect(res, Panel1.BoundsRect, Shape1.Boundsrect) then` where `res` is result overlapped rectangle if 2 rects collided. Sorry for long answer.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way is to check all 4 corners of object1 whether it's inside object 2.

```
function IsPanelCollide(Panel: TPanel; Shape: TShape): boolean;
var
  TL, TR, BL, BR: boolean;
begin
  // if TOP LEFT panel inside shape
  TL := (Panel.Top >= Shape.Top) AND (Panel.Top <= Shape.Top + Shape.Height) AND
        (Panel.Left >= Shape.Left) AND (Panel.Left <= Shape.Left + Shape.Width);

  // if TOP RIGHT panel inside shape
  TR := (Panel.Top >= Shape.Top) AND (Panel.Top <= Shape.Top + Shape.Height) AND
        (Panel.Left + Panel.Width >= Shape.Left) AND (Panel.Left + Panel.Width <= Shape.Left + Shape.Width);

  // if BOTTOM LEFT panel inside shape
  BL := (Panel.Top + Panel.Height >= Shape.Top) AND (Panel.Top + Panel.Height <= Shape.Top + Shape.Height) AND
        (Panel.Left >= Shape.Left) AND (Panel.Left <= Shape.Left + Shape.Width);

  // if BOTTOM RIGHT panel inside shape
  BR := (Panel.Top + Panel.Height >= Shape.Top) AND (Panel.Top + Panel.Height <= Shape.Top + Shape.Height) AND
        (Panel.Left + Panel.Width >= Shape.Left) AND (Panel.Left + Panel.Width <= Shape.Left + Shape.Width);

  Result := (TL) AND (TR) AND (BL) AND (BR);
end;
```

Or alternatively you could use some library such as DelphiX or anything like it that is focusing on game making. DelphiX got a method to check collision and you don't have to use your own timer, DelphiX's timer is way better and smoother for animation.

Comment: DelphiX is very, very very old library and you should not use it now, because it based on DirectDraw that obsolete now.